# Shopify Product Combinations or Addons

Tags: shopify, product

I would like to combine products in my shop.

For example, I have the following products: A, B, C. Additionally, I have the products 1, 2, 3.

All products can be bought individually. However, if a customer selects one of the products A, B or C, he/she can also select one of the products 1,2 or 3 for free (the customer will only be charged for product A, B or C).

How would I set this up in the backend? Should I set this up using product options (1,2,3 would be possible options), or do I have to generate variants of A, B, C (eg. variant A+1, A+2, etc..). If yes, how can I do this?

The important thing is, how can I set this up in a way that I can access necessary product data in the product template and that both products are added to the cart correctly (and removed from the inventory accordingly).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JavaScript/AJAX](https://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-use-ajax-api) and/or a combination of pre-fixed discount codes will help your purpose.

1. Use JavaScript/AJAX to get the item information from the cart as soon as your product **A/B/C** is added.
2. Use the above again to automatically add/update the other product **1/2/3** based on user selection.
3. Inform the user about the Discount code either as soon as the product is added to the cart or on the checkout initiation page.
4. Alternative to (3) you can add a copy of product **1/2/3** with price as zero from step 2.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I also thought about 4) - however, as far as I know, shopify does not allow to alter product prices using JS/client side code. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Once a product is added you can always make a copy of it in the admin panel and alter it. Alternatively it requires a very small code for an app to make the changes. If you are an app developer let me know.

Comment: I am a dev. yes - but new to shopify ;). Another option would be to create a specific collection of (1,2,3..) products without a price ($ = 0). On a product page of A, B, C I iterate over this zero price collection and allow the user to select one product (1,2,3) -> add to cart using JS. I think this would be an easy solution. However, an additional collection is needed. Not sure yet if this is a clean approach.

Comment: Do 1/2/3 have individual prices or by default they are always freebies?

Comment: 1,2,3 are regular products - they all have the same price. A, B, C always contains a single free 1,2,3 product. However, customers can also add additional (non-free) 1,2,3 products to the cart. I guess the zero price collection is off the table because then the shop owner would also have to create zero price products and this would mess up the inventory.

Comment: Since 1/2/3 are priced the same, the simplest way is to use discount code and informing the customer about it.

A foolproof less handling approach would be to create an app that will automatically add a variant of 1/2/3 with '0' price. Every time the combination is purchased, the same app can be used to update the inventory quantity as well.

Have a look at [parse.com](http://parse.com). I'm currently developing a complicated app on it for Shopify. For your purpose, the free version should be abundant. Coding an app there is fairly simple.

Comment: Cool, I will check it out. Thanks alot for your help & time!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95465/discussion-between-hymnz-and-ducatinerd).